# How to shift a pandas date_range by n years

Tags: pandas

Given

```
a = pandas.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-01-04')

DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

how can I obtain

```
b = pandas.date_range('2011-01-01','2011-01-04')
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

That is, how can I shift the index by exactly n years?

Adding `datetime.timedelta(days=365)` does not work for the reason that 1 year != 365 days

Comment: `a + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)` or `(a +  pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='y')).normalize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for the records:

pandas included a nice `pandas.Timedelta` function ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas.Timedelta)) that allows you to select

```
timedelta = pandas.Timedelta(1, unit='Y')
```

that added to the index above yields the correct result

```
b = a + pandas.Timedelta(1, unit='Y')
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```